# Optimizing inserts

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have some working code but am looking to make an improvement to reduce the number of roundtrips to the DB.

**Summary**

I have three database tables:

`users = [user_id, firstname, lastname]`

`relationship = [relationship_id, user_id_one, user_id_two, tag_id]`

`tag = [tag_id, tag]`

The logic in my code is this:

```
if(tagDoesntExist) { createTag(tag) }
if(checkIfUserExists(useronedetails) && checkIfUserExists(usertwodetails)) {
  createRelationship(useronedetails, usertwodetails, tag)
}
```

This consists of at least 4 DB calls.  Is it possible for me to combine the creation of the tag and relationship into the same call?

Also, as a final optimisation, could I push it all into one DB call?  That will create the relationship and tag, based on the two users existing?

Comment: You could do this using stored procedures.

Comment: @madth3 any reason why you edited my post to use the American spelling of Optimising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditional insert you can use INSERT...SELECT syntax:

```
Insert into mytable(name,cola) (select myname,vala from dual where not exists (select 1 from mytable where name=myname))
```

You can use mentioned by Philippe `insert... on duplicate key update`

You can put both commands in single string, separating them with `;`

Finally, you can write your own storing procedure doing all the tasks (check, insert if not exist, check if relationship exist and insert). This would not only be single trip to DB, but also the query sent to DB will be the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your schema it's hard to give concrete advice. Usually in such situations the solution is to use UPSERT / MERGE or something similar provided by the database. For MySQL you'll likely want to look at [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Hi Phillipe. The schema is in the original post. Richard